# SweetAlert2 executing functions while showing loading showing success after done

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I am trying to create a sweetAlert2 function where I want to fire a loading screen. And during the loading screen, I want to execute some functions, which can take some time. Afterward I want to display a fire success or error, depending on what the return will be. I tried several methods:

```
Swal.fire({
            title: 'Auto close alert!',
            html: 'In progress',
            timerProgressBar: true,
            didOpen: () => {
                try {
                    Swal.showLoading();
                    call other functions..
                    if success show 
                    Swal.fire({
                     icon: 'success',
                     title: 'Success...',
                     html: message
                    });
                   or else fire error
             catch(err){
                etc.
           }
       }
      )};
```

Now when I execute the function it waits a few seconds (executing functions) and then it shows the success or error fire, but it doesn't show the in-progress loading dialog first. Any idea how to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using setTimouts and promises:

```js
 //Start 
        Swal.fire({
                    title: 'In progress',
                    html: 'Please wait while your action is being carried out.',
                    timerProgressBar: true,
                    didOpen: () => {
                    //here it will open the in progress box
                        Swal.showLoading();
    
                        //setTimeout with 1000 or more ms is needed in order to show the inprogress box
                        setTimeout(async () => {
                            let currentRecID = currentRecord.get().id;
    
                            //load complete record
                            currentRec = record.load({
                                type: record.Type.OPPORTUNITY,
                                id: currentRecID,
                                isDynamic: true
                            });
    
                            const promiseVar = () =>
                                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                    resolve(canCreateORD(currentRec));
                                });
                            canORDbeCreated = await promiseVar();
                            //Automatically close popup so it continues with willClose
                            Swal.close();
                        }, 1000);
    
                
                    },
                    willClose: () => {
        //Show success / error box with Swal.fire
```